# Как скройлить TableView вверх, когда клавиатура закрывает курсор находящийся на TextView? Swift 4

Tags: xcode, swift, swift4

Здравствуйте!

Есть таблица с 6 динамическими секциями, в них лежит только по 1 столбцу и в нем TextView, проблема в том, что при вводе какого либо текста - клавиатура закрывает весь экран и вводимый текст попросту не видно, как сделать так, чтобы при вводе текста экран автоматически скройлился вниз? Т.е. если курсор уходит за клавиатуру, то нужно поднять tableview дабы видеть вводимый текст. У TextView скройлинг отключен, сделано для того, чтобы при вводе увеличивать саму ячейку.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Увеличиваю саму ячейку за счет этого кода:

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.endUpdates()
    UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
}
```

Нужно достичь такого [результата](https://habrastorage.org/webt/5a/6e/09/5a6e09f257c70958186951.gif)

Comment: Что-то мне кажется мой вопрос безуспешен ... :C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой способ, на это решение потратил более недели:

Скачиваем библиотеку IQKeyboardManagerSwift.

После:

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    let size = textView.bounds.size
    let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: size.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))

    if size.height != newSize.height {
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
        tableView?.beginUpdates()
        tableView?.endUpdates()
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
    }
}
```

Идеальное решение!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте такой вариант, для начала создайте `@IBOutlet weak var topConstrTableView: NSLayoutConstraint!` "соедините"   его с топ констрейном таблицы в сториборде, затем "идите" в `viewDidLoad` подпишитесь на нотификацию Клавы

```
//keyboard observers
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(YourViewController.keyboardWillAppear), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(YourViewController.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
```

затем реализуйте два метода след образом:

```
// MARK: setting key board
func keyboardWillAppear(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
        if let keyboardSize = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {   
            if yourTF.text != "" {
                self.topConstrTableView.constant = -keyboardSize.height

                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
                   self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                }
            }                            
        }
    }
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    self.topConstrTableView.constant = 0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Comment: попробовал, не работает чет

Comment: @AlexanderGovorukhin брекпоинты поставил? попадаешь  под условие ?

Comment: да, но у tableview topConstrTableView я не знаю как высоту определить, и что это self.bottomConstrainCommentView ?

Comment: @AlexanderGovorukhin https://yadi.sk/d/-FwLwCar3RwVMD, вот тестовый проект с методами который я описал выше.

Comment: это не то, что мне требуется

Comment: @AlexanderGovorukhin понял